# Firebase pod install - pod 'Firebase/Database' - Required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to install Firebase/Database like Firebase doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available_pods but when I tried I got issue.

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
```

- `Firebase/Database` required by `Podfile`

  **Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Database` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.**

**Required a higher minimum deployment target**, how can I do this?

Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP5Ba.png)

Comment: have you created Podfile?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is how I fixed it.

Step 1

Install Regular Firebase - `pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'`

Step 2

Update - `pod update`

*At this point it will take a good couple minutes to update. You should see something like this.

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase 3.2.0 (was 3.2.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (3.0.2)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.0.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 10
total pods installed.
```

Step 3

Now you should have Firebase 3. So you can add frameworks like such in your pod file then `pod update`

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'xMarket' do

end

target 'xMarketTests' do

end

target 'xMarketUITests' do

end

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod ‘Firebase/Core’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
```

Good luck!

Comment: For me first install Firebase

pod 'Firebase'

Then do a "pod update"

Then add
pod 'Firebase/xxxxx'

Answer (score 5):

In your `Podfile`, change the line `pod 'Firebase'` to `pod Firebase/Core` and run `pod update` in the project folder.

With the new Firebase, there is no need for the first line.

From the migration guide:

[image: migration]

Reference:  [Firebase.google migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by first running `pod repo update` and then running `pod install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1. pod repo remove master
2. pod setup
3. pod install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.My error below

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/AdMob` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/AdMob` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

[image]
`Targets->general->deployment target
Changed to 8.0`
 [image]

My project deployment target starts from ios 6 Since it developed in older xcode version.For new updation in `xcode 8` I made the `deployment target from ios 8`It works from me.

After fix its working

`Installing Firebase (4.0.2)
 Installing FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.1)
 Installing FirebaseCore (4.0.2)
 Installing FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.0)
 Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.20.0)
 Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)`

The latest Firebase will support from ios 8.

Answer (score 0):

or you can update the Podfile

platform :ios, '9.0'

run 'pod update'

that wo

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a similar error, running from jenkins. When I deleted the offending workspace and reran, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to delete `Podfile.lock`