# 'Higher minimum deployment target' error when installing Firebase Crash Reports Pods for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm attempting to install the Firebase Crash Reporting Pod for iOS. The core Firebase Pod installs fine, however when installing Crash Reporting, I get the following error via the terminal:

```
Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Crash` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`
```

I've tried workarounds from other similar threads (eg. [Firebase pod install - pod 'Firebase/Database' - Required a higher minimum deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365227/firebase-pod-install-pod-firebase-database-required-a-higher-minimum-deplo)), but still get the same error - is there another possible workaround? What is the minimum iOS version supported by the Firebase SDK?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image]

use deployment as 8.0 or 8.1 or 9.0

Answer (score 84):

Make sure to change the minimum deployment target in `Podfile` so for example if the minimum deployment target is meant to be `iOS 9`, it should be changed to that minimum

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
....
....
....
```

Comment: fwiw, just tried this on a project with Xcode 13.1 and bumping up from `'10.0'` to `'12.0'` and it worked.

Comment: also change the AppFrameworkInfo.plist `  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>12.0</string>`

Answer (score 55):

None of the answers listed above fixed it for me. Changing to even the latest iOS target version did not work. What worked for me was this:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: for me manual update of `platfrom :ios, '12.0'` in Podfile + this command in the same directory as the Podfile fixed it!

Comment: This does work for me! (without a need to change minimal sdk)

Comment: This + deleting podfile.lock first as said in answer below works.

Answer (score 52):

Updating your podfile platform to `platform :ios, '11.0'`  will fix the issue

Answer (score 22):

Make sure to update the platform value in ios/Podfile

platform :ios, '<minmum_version_you_want_to_support_for_pods>'

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Delete Podfile.lock

Then run:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 5):

> Steps to solve this issue.
>
> ```
> 1.) Navigate to your project folder using your terminal or iterm.
> 2.) Open your project podfile by typing :  open podfile
> 3.) In your podfile edit the deployment target below which is the 8.0.
>       platform :ios, '8.0'  
>  You may replace it with higher deployment target like 9.0, 9.1, 10.0 or higher.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Just replace platform :ios, '10.0' or the right latest version.

Comment: how can we discover what that version is? Cocoapods should tell us.

Comment: uh i guess we should just keep trying until we get it right, bcz they dont know how to write documentations!!

Comment: @funkybro Look for *.podspec file in the package repository code.

Answer (score 5):

In my case iOS 10 as a target was fine. All I had to do was:

```
pod update Firebase/Firestore
```

This updated most packages to greater versions and fixed the problem.

Comment: same case here for `Sentry`

Comment: If you're using Apple Silicon chip (M1 or M2) use - `arch -x86_64 pod update Firebase/Firestore`

Answer (score 4):

check platform :ios, 'VERSION' in your

**/node_modules/react-native/template/ios/Podfile**

update same version in your pod file fix the issue for me

Comment: Thanks for sharing.
In Flutter, I needed to change in podfile inside iOS folder.

Answer (score 3):

Open `ios` folder and find `Podfile`, then change the minimum iOS version to `11.0` as below

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Comment: platform :ios, '12.0' was what worked for my issue with a different package. Had to update this value in Xcode project -> Info

Answer (score 2):

I was running my Flutter App on MacOS and got the same error. I've tried all the stuff as above but just one solution worked for me:

Just update following line in Podfile:

```
platform :osx, '13'
```

and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the minimum iOS version supported by Firebase is 10.0. It's documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

Comment: October 2021: The doc say the minimum version is 10.0 or later

Answer (score 1):

Another scenario where this problem can occur is, if you have extensions for your app and if you specify different versions in main target and extension's target you will get this error. Make sure you have the same version of pod specified in the main target as well as in the extension's target.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the solutions mentioned above, but none seemed to work for me. What actually worked for me was simple: delete *Podfile.lock* and run *pod install* again

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me (Xcode 15), but adding the following to delete the deployment target override in the podfile did:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
        end
    end
end
```

Then `pod install`