# Unable to run my flutter app on ios simulator which is working perfectly on android simulator. Error running pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

A collaborator created this project in windows and I have cloned it in my m1 macs and trying to run it in the ios simulator.
These are the logs when I do `flutter run` in my project folder.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...

Running pod install...                                             860ms

CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `better_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_ffmpeg` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_ffmpeg/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `gallery_saver` from `.symlinks/plugins/gallery_saver/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `photo_manager` from `.symlinks/plugins/photo_manager/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `simple_image_crop` from `.symlinks/plugins/simple_image_crop/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `stripe_payment` from `.symlinks/plugins/stripe_payment/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `vibration` from `.symlinks/plugins/vibration/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_thumbnail` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_thumbnail/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `wakelock` from `.symlinks/plugins/wakelock/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_5_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/5/a/KTVHTTPCache/2.0.1/KTVHTTPCache.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_auth":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
`https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Answer (score 0):

In the podfile try assigning ios version to 10. This error as been bugging me for days now. I am not sure but this may fix it.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It's been so frustrating to understand what is going wrong in the configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to increment the minimum deployment target at `ios/flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist`, named `MinimumOSVersion`. Also try incrementing the deployment target in `ios/Podfile` :

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '11.0'
...
```

Extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490417/1085978) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40705146/1085978)