# App fails to run when I add better_player fllutter package to my dependencies in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

**Describe the bug**

Cannot run any flutter project on Android Emulator or iPhone Simulator once better_player is added to dependencies (even if it is not used)

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. In Flutter 2.8.0., I ran flutter create new_2_8_0 for a new basic project. (the problem is the same with 2.8.1)
2. Running this project on my Pixel 2 AP31 (android-x64) emulator works fine, albeit with some warning messages:

```
Downloading android-arm-profile/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm-release/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm64-profile/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-arm64-release/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-x64-profile/darwin-x64 tools...
Downloading android-x64-release/darwin-x64 tools...
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:54784/IwKzEgbyFWk=/ws
D/EGL_emulation( 7334): app_time_stats: avg=8324.12ms min=13.49ms max=16634.76ms count=2
```

3. Then, I ran `flutter pub add better_player` in the directory of the project.
4. Trying to run the project again yields many errors (full log in this Pastebin link as it is too long: https://pastebin.com/aTazjdi1):

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Note: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_android-2.0.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/pathprovider/PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0dbe33926dedae4110b9532ba617aff6/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/185d46b6321985f52dcc07c04b9e0199/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.31.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/321b0404bca10e53dde201e006f9bf05/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3b4231ab8018cfab964f203a82e1a180/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.31.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/683fded33b117c0eb9bb9deabca1a71e/work-runtime-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/work-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/74e0b9ecf42ab18509b57e0cb0171618/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7ed1fc227d449123990dfe95b91bbf13/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/9feb92637239c001fff195574ed1097d/jetified-lifecycle-runtime-ktx-2.4.0-beta01-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bd92f9b27f3f577322c07e31476e006e/jetified-core-ktx-1.6.0-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (67, 20): Unresolved reference: max
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (68, 20): Unresolved reference: min

e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (112, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7ed1fc227d449123990dfe95b91bbf13/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (131, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7ed1fc227d449123990dfe95b91bbf13/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (132, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7ed1fc227d449123990dfe95b91bbf13/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (136, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from /Users/nathan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7ed1fc227d449123990dfe95b91bbf13/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (136, 46): Unresolved reference: isNotEmpty
e: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/better_player-0.0.79/android/src/main/kotlin/com/jhomlala/better_player/BetterPlayer.kt: (140, 44): For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

.
.
.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':better_player:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 30s
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
    Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update /Users/nathan/flutter_projects/new_2_8_0/android/build.gradle:
    ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

5. I then followed the suggesttions to change the Kotlin version, then ran it again, and got this result:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Note: /Users/nathan/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_android-2.0.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/pathprovider/PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 68779 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:432)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: null
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.1.62.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:78)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 68779 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.error(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P.a(SourceFile:740)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$h.a(SourceFile:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(SourceFile:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:36)
    ... 38 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
[!] App requires Multidex support
    Flutter multidex handling is disabled. If you wish to let the tool configure multidex, use the --mutidex flag.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

6. For iOS Simulator, I get this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `better_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `wakelock` from `.symlinks/plugins/wakelock/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "better_player":
      In Podfile:
        better_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios`)
    Specs satisfying the `better_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**Better Player version**

- Version: better_player: ^0.0.79

**Smartphone:**

Android Emulator:

- Name: Pixel_2_API_31
- CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86_64)
- Path: /Users/nathan/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_31.avd
- Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 31)
- Skin: pixel_2
- SD Card: 512M

iPhone Simulator:

- Version 13.2 (972.2)
- SimulatorKit 613.1
- CoreSimulator 783.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the Android error, it tells you that you need to enable `multiDex` in your project, here is how

in `android/app/build.gradle` add this line `multiDexEnabled = true` in the `defaultConfig`

your `defaultConfig` should look something like this

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled = true
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

regarding the iOS error it says

> dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

so increase the minimum deployment target. you can find it in `ios/flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist` named `MinimumOSVersion` and looking like this

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key> 
<string>9.0</string>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! I'm confused about this fix for the iOS error though. I followed the answer for this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602469/higher-minimum-deployment-target-error-when-installing-firebase-crash-reports , and included this line: `platform :ios, '10.0'` in my `Podfile`, which they say is supposed to do the trick, but it still didn't. Is 10.0 still too low? How do I check what is required?

Comment: from here: https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer/#/install

this package needs version 11.


"Set deployment info of your project to min. iOS 11.0 version."

Comment: I see, thanks for the rapid response. I didn't know there was another set of documentation in addition to the one on pub.dev :/