# Can't build ipa for Flutter project [CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":]

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I’ve spent days stuck on this. I’ve tried many flutter pub and pod commands but nothing works. I've also deleted the pods folder and re-added the firebase-ios-sdk.

I keep seeing this :

```
  In Podfile:
    firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 9.1.12, which depends on
      Firebase/Analytics (= 9.2.0) was resolved to 9.2.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Core (= 9.2.0) was resolved to 9.2.0, which depends on
          FirebaseAnalytics (~> 9.2.0) was resolved to 9.2.0, which depends on
            FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 9.2.0) was resolved to 9.2.0, which depends on
              GoogleAppMeasurement (= 9.2.0)

    google_mobile_ads (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mobile_ads/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 8.13.0) was resolved to 8.13.0, which depends on
        GoogleAppMeasurement (< 9.0, >= 7.0)
```

So I got desperate, deleted the whole ios folder and then run `flutter create .` it regenerated everything and then I run `flutterfire configure`. Everything seemed fine but I still can't build or run the app targeting ios. I think somehow, xcode is preserving some settings or files and `pod cache clean` is not even deleting that. What should I delete/nuke in xcode? I'm tired.

Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Post your podfile here

Comment: I've added that now but it's generated, the only think I usually do is to uncomment the ios version to set it to 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Edit] [google_mobile_ads 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/changelog#200) has been released to fix this issue

So I found the solution. After staring at `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` for hours I thought why not just manually change the version in the `.symlinks` folder. I did not work and I got some error about some missing credential. So then I searched for `google_mobile_ads ios` and found out that the latest version available is so high up. The maximum version flutter uses is from `2021‑11‑17` last year. My guess is there might be trouble migrating it to SDK v9 (I don't know what that is). Anyways that's just a theory, I don't know much about iOS plugins.

Now the solution, I figured at least someone on github has had this same issue and I was right [google_mobile_ads](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/594) it's a p1 issue so hopefully it'll be fixed soon. For now, just replace the dependency like this:

```
  google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter
      ref: 356875362ddb2ac2e0056385d2729c093722fb8d
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
```

And it'll work like @jonafeucht on github said. It's a workaround but I've found no isssues with it so far. Although I had to fix a few other issues I created for myself in an attempt to get the project to run.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the culprit is firebase_analytics. The moment I removed this package, the code is working fine.

Once you remove firebase_analytics package.

- Delete ios/Pods folder
- Delete ios/Podfile.lock

and run these commands

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter run`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it works but what if you need firebase_analytics in your project?

Comment: It is expected to have a new release in a few days. Keep an eye out.

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete

.symlinks filder

Pods

Podfile.lock

Run flutter clean

Then try building it

Comment: Same error, I'm thinking it's related to cocoapods persisting some info but I don't have any native ios dev experience

Comment: Please take a backup of your project. Run pod deintegrate and pod install

Comment: Ok, will do and see what happens

Comment: Update: didn't work

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes it's the same error

Comment: One other solution is to create a new project and add dependencies and lib in it and build it again.

Comment: I've the exact same issue, spent one day trying to solve this, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add platfrom :ios, '10.0'

[image: 1]

Hi, try adding `platfrom :ios, '10.0'` to your ios/Podfile,

solution from ['Higher minimum deployment target' error when installing Firebase Crash Reports Pods for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602469/higher-minimum-deployment-target-error-when-installing-firebase-crash-reports)