# Unable to find a specification for `GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)` depended upon by `FirebaseAnalytics`

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

Unable to find a specification for `GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)` depended upon by `FirebaseAnalytics` i got this error when i m try to install firebase pod file .

**I already try this solution** . `pod repo update --verbose`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Rehabtask' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Rehabtask

  target 'RehabtaskTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'RehabtaskUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

pod 'Firebase'

end
```

**Here is error log**

[image: Error]

Comment: Please check this . http://stackoverflow.com/a/37365721/4910767

Comment: platform :ios, '8.0' platform change @BadalShah i need this in ios 7.0

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hems3112/efd2d10a83a56b401ef0256deca7774a

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nx6ghgl3kpfsns/ServiceCall.swift?dl=0

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hems3112/d05055eda3f0c9ed135a75b6da64961d

Comment: Database https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9nbs37okcwiy3x/Database%20File.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hems3112/0c2a28803e40db38e18fa2966d9165cc Model

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5jajq6itakzirw/Archive.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed your podfile and work fine with iOS7 , so may be there wrong in your pod try to do remove pods and install it again , because of pod install take more time try this suggest solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904450/5251783 , hope this help you .

Comment: i will try this answer wait

Comment: its take more then 15 minutes and its still show me Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Comment: thats normal because size of cooapods big as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21852985/5251783

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131150/discussion-between-hosny-and-himanshu-moradiya).

Answer (score 0):

```
 func PracticalTask(){
        let string1 : NSString = txtfirst.text! as NSString
        let string2 : NSString = txtSecond.text! as NSString
        let alphaNumericCharacterSet = string1.description.removeCharacters(from: "0123456789")
        print("no digits",alphaNumericCharacterSet) // will print: Vishal
        var result = ""
        string1.enumerateSubstrings(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: string1.length), options: .byComposedCharacterSequences, using: { substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop in

            if string2.length >= substringRange.upperBound{
                if !string2.substring(with: substringRange).contains((substring?.characters.first)!){
                    result = result + substring!
                }
            }else{
                result = result + substring!
            }

        })
        string2.enumerateSubstrings(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: string2.length), options: .byComposedCharacterSequences, using: { substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop in
            if string1.length >= substringRange.upperBound{
                print(string1.substring(with: substringRange))
                if !string1.substring(with: substringRange).contains((substring?.characters.first)!){
                   result = result + substring!
                }
            }else{
                 result = result + substring!
            }

        })

        print("String after removed duplicate characters : \(result)")
        lblresult.text = result
    }
```