# Issues with Firebase Performance Monitoring and App Indexing

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-app-indexing, firebase-performance

I'm using some pods of Firebase SDK in my project; actually I'm using Firebase App Indexing also I need to use Firebase Performance Monitoring  framework but when I'm installing it (I'm using Cocoa Pods 1.2.0) the logs shows me this:

> Specs satisfying the 'Firebase/AppIndexing' dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Obviously I change the deploy target to the higher version posible but the message still the same; I think that for some reasons App Indexing and Performance Monitoring couldn't live together or I'm implementing it wrong...

Language.- ObjC
Firebase framework .- 4.0.2

Any suggestions?

Comment: found a similar problem related to Firebase that has been answered. Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365721/4868964) helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase AppIndexing was [deprecated for iOS in Firebase 3.7.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) and removed in Firebase 4.0.0.  Since Firebase Performance Monitoring was introduced in 4.0.0, there is no Firebase version that supports both.

The recommendation is to migrate from AppIndexing to [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).