# Firebase Performance Monitoring in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods, firebase-performance

I am trying to install pod Firebase/Performance as mention in Firebase doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available_pods but when I tried I got issue.

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Performance` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Performance` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: even my minimum iOS deployment target is 8.0

Comment: Which line do you have at the top of your podfile? something like platform :ios, '9.0' , post your full podfile

Comment: @RyanHeitner platform :ios, '8.0'

Comment: Have you included Firebase/Core ?

Comment: @RyanHeitner yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365721/1463518 does this help

Comment: @RyanHeitner Thanks i am trying with it again.

Answer (score 1):

That error is misleading. This message often occurs if you have dependencies (of Firebase Performance) that are pinned to specific versions that are lower that what Firebase Performance needs. For example, if you've pinned Firebase/Analytics to 3.x, you'd get that error because Firebase Performance requires 4.x of Firebase/Core.

In summary, try removing any version pins related to Firebase specs in your Podfile.